# Why do I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on launch in Android 4.1 but not 4.4?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

My main activity launches just fine in 4.4, but not when using 4.1. Then I get:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.name.thing.other.MyActivity$1 ...
and the rest of the stack trace.

Manifest:

http://pastebin.com/KSNzgEZy

Comment: post the error details.

Comment: @Shriram, could you be more specific? It's my launch activity that isn't found, so the rest of the trace is not informative.

Comment: show your manifest file